# How do I fill an ArrayList with random generated products?

Tags: java, traveling-salesman, hill-climbing

I'd like some help with getting a randomizer working for my code. I am working on a hill-climbing algorithm for a school project. The algorithm works only I don't know how I can make it add random product(locations it needs to visit.)

Here is the main class. If I have to provide anymore then feel free to ask and I will.

```
package hillclimbing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Driver {
    private ArrayList<Product> initialProducts = new ArrayList<Product>(Arrays.asList(
            new Product("Tandpasta", 42.3601, -71.0589),
            new Product("Banaan", 29.7064, -95.3698),
            new Product("Kaas", 30.2672, -97.7431),
            new Product("Laptop", 37.7749, -122.4194),
            new Product("Vliegtuig", 39.0000, -104.0000),
            new Product("Robot", 34.0000, -118.0000),
            new Product("Magazijn", 41.0000, -87.0000),
            new Product("Kubus", 40.0000, -74.0000),
            new Product("Doos", 32.0000, -96.0000),
            new Product("Lego", 47.0000, -122.0000)
    ));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Driver driver = new Driver();
    Route route = new Route(driver.initialProducts);
    printHeading(route);
    System.out.print(route + " |   " + route.getTotalDistance());
    new HillClimbing().findShortestRoute(route);
}

public static void printHeading(Route route){
    String headingColumn1 = "Route";
    String remainingHeadingColumns = "Distance (in miles) | Compare adjacent to current route";
    int productNamesLength = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < route.getProducts().size(); x++) productNamesLength += route.getProducts().get(x).getName().length();
    int arrayLength = productNamesLength + route.getProducts().size()*2;
    int partialLength = (arrayLength - headingColumn1.length()/2);
    for(int x = 0; x < partialLength; x++)System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print(headingColumn1);
    for(int x = 0; x < partialLength; x++)System.out.print(" ");
    if((arrayLength % 2) == 0)System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.println(" | " + remainingHeadingColumns);
    productNamesLength += remainingHeadingColumns.length() + 3;
    for(int x = 0; x < productNamesLength + route.getProducts().size()*2; x++)System.out.print("-");
    System.out.println("");
}

}
```

And here is the randomizer that should be able to fill/replace the ArrayList

```
package hillclimbing;

import java.util.*;

public class RandomProducten {

public HashMap<Integer, Product> producten;

public RandomProducten(int aantal){
    Random rand = new Random();
    producten = new HashMap<Integer, Product>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= aantal;i++){
        boolean geaccepteerd = false;
        int randx = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        int randy = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;

        while (! geaccepteerd){
            if (hasDuplicates(randx, randy)){
                randx = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
                randy = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
            } else {
                geaccepteerd = true;
            }
        }

        Product p = new Product("Product " + i, randx, randy);
        producten.put(i, p);
    }
}

public boolean hasDuplicates(int x, int y) {
    boolean antwoord = false;

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Product> entry : producten.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().getX() == x && entry.getValue().getY() == y){
            antwoord = true;
        }
    }

    return antwoord;
}

public String toString(){
    String antwoord = "";

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Product> entry : producten.entrySet()) {
        antwoord += entry.getValue();
    }

    return antwoord;
}

}
```

Comment: Please clarify the problem you found and provide some example.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking since you don't write about any issue, but one hint I can give: Instead of going `while (random values not different) { create new ones; }` I'd go with a shuffle and take the first x entries, at least if you don't have a list of a million members. Also, you should always write any code in english. "producten", "geaccepteerd" and "antwoord" is not english. Makes it harder for different nationalities to read your code.

Comment: You need to write what exactly does not work so we know where to look.